# Scale to fill for custom views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created custom view based on xib file. I initialise view like that:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customXib" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I've tried to use `self.view.frame = self.bound` but after this line autolayout doesn't work.

I use my custom view in other xib file (mainXib). I put UIView to mainXib and change class name to my custom view. Mode is set to 'Scale To Fill'. Unfortunately my custom view has size from customXib file and doesn't 'Scale To Fill'.

What should I do to make my custom view resizable using autolayouts? I would like to make my custom view stretched to size from mainXib. The only solution I see now is to don't use autolayouts and do all sizing part in `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`, but I believe it can be done with autolayouts.